# Vertical algin: top different type of tag in LI Node

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am a creating a collapsible tree-style UL list dynamically. The height of Li node is dynamically changing.

```
<ul class="tree">
    <li> Item 1. <svg>some tags</svg><button1><button2></li>
    <li> Item 2. <svg>some tags</svg><button1><button2></li>
    <li> Item 3. <svg>some tags</svg><button1><button2>
         <ul>
             .  . . .similar li code
         </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The height of svg may vary at different instance of time.

My goal is to vertically align the text, svg and button to top.

I tried the following techniques

1. using css `height:Xpx;` and `height:Xpx;` by setting them to equal value
2. Changing the parent ul node `display:table` property and corresponding child li node to `display:table-cell` or `display:table-row;`.

My view currently looks like this -

[image]

Picture show how miss aligned the things are. My goal is to vertically align to top.

Comment: did you use vertical-align: middle?

Comment: if you mean with 'display:table' method yes I tried both middle and top. but not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understood you exactly, but take a look here:
https://jsfiddle.net/houxco2k/

I think it will do the thing:

```
li{
    display: table-cell;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;


}
li svg{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;

}
```